Override wallet interaction (connect, signIn, signTransaction)
I'd like to programmatically "act as wallet" from my custom Chrome extension. I'm using Phantom myself and I thought I'd "just override some methods" and that it would work, but this doesn't seem to be the case. For instance, I inject the following script on the page (which I believe uses Wallet Adapter, but it at least supports Phantom):
const p = (window as any).phantom;

p.solana.signMessage = (message:Uint8Array):Uint8Array => {
    console.log('signing', message);
    return new Uint8Array(nacl.sign.detached(message, kp.secretKey) as ArrayBuffer);
}

However this method supposedly is put in some encode() method, but when I attach a debugger this method receives an undefined and not the Uint8Array which I'm returning from my signMessage method...
It feels I'm going into a bit too much of a hacky solution (which is not a problem if it will work eventually, but I'm not sure if it will via this way).
Anyone perhaps with a suggestion on how to have my own Chrome extension "act as" wallet for connecting, signing in and sending a transaction? I just have my private key available hardcoded as a KeyPair object.
Any guidance would be highly appreciated!

By "connecting", "signing in" and "sending transaction" you ultimately mean you want to create your custom wallet like Phantom, is this what you mean? If not, what's your objective by creating a Chrome extension? Why not just have a custom wallet in your dApp?
But if you mean to totally override the phantom extension - that would be completely impossible. you cannot simply do that, else we will have so many security issues if that was possible.
